# Upload file in Selenium using AutoIt?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-design, test-strategy, autoit

I'm trying to `upload` a file using `Selenium` on `Windows 7` using `AutoIt` following this tutorial http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/.

The web page I'm using is this one http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/ (click on `Choose File` button).

Here is my Java code

```
package practiceTestCases;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class AutoIt_00 {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form");

    driver.findElement(By.id("photo")).click();

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/testAutoIt_03.exe");

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //driver.close();

   }

}
```

and this is the `AutoIt` code

```
#region --- Au3Recorder generated code Start (v3.3.9.5 KeyboardLayout=00000410)  ---
WinWaitActive("C:\Users\520\Desktop\testAutoIt_03.au3 - SciTE","")
Send("{TAB}")
WinWaitActive("C:\Users\520\Desktop\testAutoIt_03.au3 * SciTE","")
Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
WinWaitActive("Caricamento file","")
MouseClick("left",242,415,1)
Send("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{UP}{UP}{UP}{ENTER}")
#endregion --- Au3Recorder generated code End ---
```

I've tried to move in the window where select my file using keyboard and not the mouse hoping to simplify my job.

When execute the `Java` code it works, connect to the web site, open the window for the file choice, but after this nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe don't use the generated code, but the example from this answer : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12872/3201 and do you really need auto-it, you can upload files with WebDriver code it self often: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12852/3201

Comment: Ok it's working now ..... Do you've any sample for the download, always using AutoIt?

Comment: better to ask a new question how to download with Auto-IT :)