# How to handle file upload and download using Robot Class?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to build a framework using Selenium. There is a scenario where I need to download a file, and there is another where I need to upload one.
I've gone through the option in AutoIt, but it doesn't allow me to put in a varying filename. Then I came across Robot where in I can send custom strings. 
However, for some reason, the piece of code is not entering text into the field.
I see that the cursor is in the field, but the text is not getting entered. 
What could be the reason?

Also, is there an option to make the mouse click on a particular button, say Open/Cancel using Robot?(Just like AutoIT can do)

```
    String text = "sampledoc.txt";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(text);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: For uploads using Robot, check out this awesome answer by Manali J here : http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/12871/7313

Comment: great solution when all other methods failed to work..Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Upload**

No need to use Autoit or Robot class for uploading a file in browser.

using WebDriver itself we can achieve that.

Pass the absolute file path to file locator.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']")).sendKeys("/home/test/uploadthis.png");
```

**Download**

For downloading a file we need to set it in browser preferences. It varies based on browsers.

**Firefox**

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","/home/Desktop/");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/csv");

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Upload File
2. Copy your Path in Clipboard (as Shown in the code)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> using robot class

   ```
   StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(file);
   Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
   clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, pressing an <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> works. Code:

```
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(DocSampleFilePath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null); //copy the above string to clip board     
        Robot robot;
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(2000); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); //paste the copied string into the dialog box
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); //enter
```