# Handling Popup using selenium - how to switch back on parent window from child?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, c#

So I have to upload a document, and the popup for file explorer loads and my code can find the document I need, but how do I then switch back to my original browser?
Here is the code:

```
        driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys("C:\\Users\\Saurav\\Downloads\\GGPrezi.pptx");
```

It is able to select the document but now I need to get back to the original browser, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you sure that your code can find the document? Because from what I know selenium webdriver cannot interact with OS pop-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium cannot handle any OS based dialogues like file browser. So if the upload element is visible on the page, then instead of using `switchTo()` function you should directly use `sendKeys()` function to upload a document as shown below:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadElement")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Saurav\\Downloads\\GGPrezi.pptx");
```

So the control will always be on the original browser.

For more information just go through following link:
[Upload a file in Selenium Webdriver using sendKeys](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/upload-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver-using-sendkeys)

If you want to learn to switch between multiple windows using selenium, then below mentioned link might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741257/how-to-change-between-pages-with-selenium

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `driver.switch_to.default_content()`. I am not sure but the Java version of webdriver should be

```
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Saurav -

1. When you are able to select your document perfectly, anyways control/focus will be automatically shifted to your main browser window. Isn't it really?
2. Still if you wanted to handle from code, I will suggest to go through [How to handle browser pop-up](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20600/how-to-handle-the-browser-pop-ups-in-selenium-ide/20602#20602). Core concept will remain same.
3. If you want to use `sendKeys()` to upload a file using selenium web driver, make sure that the input element is visible on the page. Once the element is visible, you should simply use below mentioned code:

> driver.findElement(By.id("myUploadElement")).sendKeys("absolute path of the file");

You should not click on the browse button as it will open windows dialogue box and selenium web driver won't work.

`myUploadElement` is the id of that element and in `sendKeys()` you have to specify the absolute path of the content you want to upload (Image,video etc). Selenium will do the rest for you.

If `sendkeys()` wont work at all, then you can also use `SikuliX` to handle uploading files.

`SikuliX` can be used as it automates everything that you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components.

Give a try, Hope it helps !