# Is it possible to automate drag and drop from a file in system to a website in selenium using TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

Is it possible to automate drag and drop from a file in system to a website in selenium using TestNG? Same as we do in Gmail where we can send attachment by drag and drop operation? please suggest.

Comment: Yes you can do it using the following command: Actions act = new Actions(driver); act.clickAndHold(webelement).perform(); act.MoveToElement(element).Release(); FYI: Draganddrop(element1,element2) command was available in previous versions of selenium but not in newer versions.

Comment: i have to upload the file from the desktop. how clickAndHold will work with that??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes it's possible to drop a file with Selenium via a script injection. The script needs to create an `<input>` web element to receive the file sent by `SendKeys`. Then simulate the `dragenter`, `dragover` and `drop` events on the targeted element with the file set in the `dataTransfer` object.

This example drops an image from the file system on a drop area:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("http://html5demos.com/file-api");

// locate the drop area
WebElement droparea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#holder"));

// drop the file
DropFile(new File("C:\\Downloads\\image.png"), droparea, 0, 0);
```

The `DropFile` method:

```
public static void DropFile(File filePath, WebElement target, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
    if(!filePath.exists())
        throw new WebDriverException("File not found: " + filePath.toString());

    WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)target).getWrappedDriver();
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    String JS_DROP_FILE =
        "var target = arguments[0]," +
        "    offsetX = arguments[1]," +
        "    offsetY = arguments[2]," +
        "    document = target.ownerDocument || document," +
        "    window = document.defaultView || window;" +
        "" +
        "var input = document.createElement('INPUT');" +
        "input.type = 'file';" +
        "input.style.display = 'none';" +
        "input.onchange = function () {" +
        "  var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect()," +
        "      x = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width >> 1))," +
        "      y = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height >> 1))," +
        "      dataTransfer = { files: this.files };" +
        "" +
        "  ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'drop'].forEach(function (name) {" +
        "    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');" +
        "    evt.initMouseEvent(name, !0, !0, window, 0, 0, 0, x, y, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);" +
        "    evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer;" +
        "    target.dispatchEvent(evt);" +
        "  });" +
        "" +
        "  setTimeout(function () { document.body.removeChild(input); }, 25);" +
        "};" +
        "document.body.appendChild(input);" +
        "return input;";

    WebElement input =  (WebElement)jse.executeScript(JS_DROP_FILE, target, offsetX, offsetY);
    input.sendKeys(filePath.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(input));
}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but RemoteWebDriver cannot be resolved to a type. At least not in Selenium-java 3.141.59  
I added selenium-remote-driver (version 3.141.59) to my pom and then Eclipse could find it, but that version of RemoteWebDriver does not have getWrappedDriver().  :-(  What else can I do?

Comment: @Tihamer, the `RemoteWebDriver` type is still present to this date: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Yes, RemoteWebDriver definitely exists.
However, I just did a cntl-F search on the web page you gave me: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html but it was not be able to locate "getWrappedDriver".  
It is not in the Version 3.141.59 source code either, which I'm looking at in Eclipse. However, I did a google search and found the function at:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html
I'm trying to figure out how to use it...

Comment: I got it to work, and it works beautifully!
Here is the change I made in the  line that sets the driver:
     WebDriver driver = ((org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement)target).getWrappedDriver();

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoIT it is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate task.

You can upload multiple files.

Please refer [This](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit)

Hope it helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it. Selenium only interacts with HTML element.

You can handle uploading file case by using below code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

element = driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload")

element.send_keys("C:\myfile.txt")
```

**p/s: I copy this code from reference link below**

Reference: [How can I work with file uploads during a Webdriver test?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)

Comment: I have tried the above code.it gives me the following Exception.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: The above code will only work when upload/browse button displayed with a text field else the above code will not work

Comment: the above code is for file upload with selenium and python,not for selenium+java.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm asking here the question regrading the dropfile method.
this function was working fine but since upgraded the seleniumm webdriver to 4/4.01, The c# compained about RemoteWebElement is deprecated. How to fix that. Kind Regards.

[image: deprecated]