# Can we Drag and Drop multiple desktop images at the same time to web page using selenium - Java through script ingestion

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I found the below article for image upload using script ingestion. But this script is working for a single file at a time but I want to drag and drop multiple files at the same time.

My client doesn't want to use any 3rd party tool. So can someone please help with how can I enhance the below script for multiple images at the same time?

Note: If anyone suggests any better approach could be helpful that..

Article: [Drag and drop](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/22191/is-it-possible-to-automate-drag-and-drop-from-a-file-in-system-to-a-website-in-s)

Answer (score 1):

If the input type is [multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) you can send a comma-delineated string of file paths.